# Running iOS7 Simulator alongside iOS8 in Xamarin

Tags: ios7, xamarin, ios8, ios-simulator, xcode6

I've upgraded to XCode 6, reinstalled the iOS 7.1 simulator and now my Xamarin app is terminated immediately after the launch image is shown. The Application Output is as follows:

```
Starting iPad 2
Launching application
Application launched. PID = 97972
Press enter to terminate the application
>
Application Terminated
```

If I choose the iOS8 simulator then it runs without issue.

Are there any settings I need to manually change or is there anywhere I can get better debug information?

**Update: System Log Trace**

```
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local CoreSimulatorBridge[7807] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: com.HIDDENAPPNAME
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local CoreSimulatorBridge[7807] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Not creating progress for LSApplicationProxy: com.HIDDENAPPNAME since it is not a placeholder.
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[7800] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/Users/chriskoiak/Documents/Initial/Mobile Clients/HIDDEN_CLIENT_NAME/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/HIDDENAPPNAME.app" requested by CoreSimulatorBridge
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[7800] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app com.HIDDENAPPNAME
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[7800] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 install_application: Performing developer delta patch
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local installd[7800] <Notice>: 0xb0115000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.02s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.03s
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local lsd[7811] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating identifier store
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local SpringBoard[7804] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: still-camera is static and will never generate a notification
Oct 14 16:40:22 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local SpringBoard[7804] <Error>: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:835: stand-alone-contacts is static and will never generate a notification
Oct 14 16:40:23 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local backboardd[7794] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.HIDDENAPPNAME[0x9262]' exited abnormally with signal 5: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Oct 14 16:40:32 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local lsd[7811] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Currently 0 installed placeholders: (
)
Oct 14 16:40:42 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local mstreamd[7799] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.
Oct 14 16:40:42 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local mstreamd[7799] <Notice>: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x3a1c630>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
Oct 14 16:40:42 Chriss-MacBook-Pro-2.local mstreamd[7799] <Notice>: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to the "Linker behaviour". Updating this from "Don't Link" to "Link SDK assemblies only" resolved my issue.

Comment: Just had this same issue. Was pulling my hair out until I changed the linking behavior and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in Xamarin.iOS v8.0 that could cause this behavior.

The bug was fixed in Xamarin.iOS v8.2, so make sure you're using the latest stable version (which is Xamarin.iOS 8.2).

Comment: Thanks Rolf, but I'm already using Xamarin.iOS v8.2.0.193


Build date: 2014-10-03 00:25:37-0400

Comment: In the simulator, open `Debug -> Open System Log...` and see if anything useful is printed there when you try to launch an app.

Comment: I've updated the original post with the System Log. I can't see anything that points to the cause of the error.

Comment: `Application 'UIKitApplication:com.HIDDENAPPNAME[0x9262]' exited abnormally with signal 5: Trace/BPT trap: 5` - check the Console app for crash reports (they'll show up under the "User Diagnostic Reports")

Comment: @RolfBjarneKvinge FWIW, I just had this issue as well on Xamarin.iOS 8.4.0.38 in alpha channel. Had to change the linking setting to get it to work.